# Como criar um dicionário através de uma string

Tags: python

Boa tarde,

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma dicionario através de uma string, por exemplo:

Eu crio um loop for dentro de uma lista e esse loop sempre me devolvera um nome:

```
lista = ['ameixa', 'banana', 'caju']
for i in lista:
    print(i)

output = ameixa
banana
caju
```

Existe uma maneira de criar um dicionário através dessas strings ? Seguindo o mesmo exemplo de cima eu gostaria que meus outputs fossem:

```
ameixa = {}
banana = {}
caju = {}
```

Isso é possível ? Meu objetivo com isso é importar e transformar todos os jsons que utilizo no meu código em dicionários no momento em que inicio minha aplicação.

**** Edit ****

Exatamente como mencionado nos comentários eu gostaria de criar dicionários dinamicamente.

Para ilustrar melhor a minha situação:

Eu tenho vários arquivos chamados "ameixa.json", "banana.json" e "caju.json".

O que eu quero fazer é pegar o conteúdo de cada um desses jsons e transformar num dicionário que sempre recebera o mesmo nome ( ameixa.json dentro do meu código vai se tornar dicionário um chamado ameixa).

Foi baseado nessa necessidade que eu pensei em criar uma lista com o nome de cada um desses jsons e utilizar um loop para criar dicionários vazios pois uma vez que eu tenho os dicionários criados eu consigo fazer a manipulação.

Se por acaso conhecerem algum outro modo de transformar jsons em dicionários dinamicamente eu serei muito grato, mas por enquanto é nessa ideia que estou investindo.

Comment: Ao meu ver isso não faz muito sentido. Como saberá que `caju` está na lista original e, portanto, existe o dicionário?

Comment: Se entendi direito você quer criar dinamicamente dicionários com os nomes dos campos que estão na lista. Existe como fazer mas como foi dito você não terá como saber se existem os dicionários, a não ser que, exista um padrão que seja sempre igual.

Comment: Sem conhecer o seu contexto eu chutaria que a solução talvez seja, criar uma lista de dicts vazia, fazer um loop na lista `['ameixa', 'banana', 'caju']` e então adicionar os dicionários cujas chaves seriam os elementos dessa lista, no final vc teria algo assim: `[{'ameixa': {}}, {'banana': {}}, {'caju': {}}]`

Comment: Assim vc poderia construir uma funcao para acessar os dicionários em `dicts` atavés dos elementos da lista original.

Comment: Sidon se eu conseguir transformar a minha lista com os nomes em dicionários dessa forma que você fez eu já consigo realizar o que preciso, porém eu não consegui entender como executar essa ideia que você sugeriu. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Se vc ressolveu seu problema inspirado na minha ideia, vc conseguiu entender a essencia da minha solução, não?

Comment: Ok, tava sonolento e tinha entendido q vc ja tinha resolvido :-), respondi a pergunta com a minha ideia para a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eu tenho vários arquivos chamados "ameixa.json", "banana.json" e "caju.json".
>
> O que eu quero fazer é pegar o conteúdo de cada um desses jsons e transformar num dicionário que sempre recebera o mesmo nome ( ameixa.json dentro do meu código vai se tornar dicionário um chamado ameixa).

Como os nomes dos arquivos são dinâmicos, acredito que uma boa abordagem seria ter um dicionário de dicionários. Um dicionário centralizador onde vão estar os conteúdos de todos os arquivos.

---

Vou usar de exemplo os seguintes arquivo e conteúdos:

- **ameixa.json**

  ```
    {"nome": "Ameixa"}
  ```
- **banana.json**

  ```
    {"nome": "Banana"}
  ```
- **caju.json**

  ```
    {"nome": "Caju"}
  ```

---

Primeiro passo seria ler estes arquivos da pasta onde eles estão (vou supor que estão na mesma pasta do script python).

Você pode usar a função [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) para iterar sobre todas as entradas de um arquivo (arquivos, diretórios, symlinks, etc). Ex.:

```
import os

with os.scandir() as it:
    for entry in it:
        pass
```

Agora que estamos iterando nas entradas, temos que selecionar apenas os arquivos que nos interessam, que são os arquivos JSON

```
import os

with os.scandir() as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.json'):
            pass
```

Essa é a hora de:

- extrair o nome do arquivo para usar como chave no nosso dicionário "centralizador"
- ler o conteúdo do arquivo
- fazer o *parsing* do JSON usando [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- atribuir o resultado do *parsing* ao dicionário

O código final ficaria assim:

```
import os
import json
from pprint import pprint  # apenas para fins de apresentação

frutas = dict()

# Lê todas as entradas do diretório atual
with os.scandir() as it:
    # Itera sobre estas entradas
    for entry in it:
        # Se for um arquivo JSON
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith('.json'):
            # Abre o arquivo para leitura
            with open(entry.path, 'r') as f:
                key = entry.name[:-5]  # elimina o ".json" do nome do arquivo
                value = f.read()  # lê todo o conteúdo do arquivo
                frutas[key] = json.loads(value)  # faz o parsing do JSON e salva no dicionário

pprint(frutas)
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-3704096333) do código funcionando.</sup>

O resultado fica:

```
{'ameixa': {'nome': 'Ameixa'},
 'banana': {'nome': 'Banana'},
 'caju': {'nome': 'Caju'}}
```

Comment: Atendeu completamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Colocando em prática a ideia apresentada nos comentários da pergunta:

Primeiro vamos criar uma função que recebe uma lista de dicionários e uma chave, através da chave o dicionario é retornado:

```
def get_dict(dicts, key):
    for d in dicts:
        result = d.get(key)
        if result:
            return result
    return None
```

Agora vamos criar a lista e os dicionarios:

```
lista = ['ameixa', 'banana', 'caju']

# Criando os dicionarios:
dicts = []
n = 10
for x in lista:
    dicts.append({x: {n}})
    n+=1

# Apresentando o conteudo dos dicionarios
print('Conteúdo dos dicionários:',dicts, sep='\n')
```

Saida:

```
Conteúdo dos dicionários:
[{'ameixa': {10}}, {'banana': {11}}, {'caju': {12}}]
```

Agora vamos acessar o dicionario `banana` através da lista:

```
print('Dic ref ao segundo elemento da lista:',get_dict(dicts, lista[1]), sep='\n')
```

Saida:

```
Dic ref ao segundo elemento da lista:
{11}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/dynamics-dicts)